# Performance во Flutter

Tags: flutter

Есть вопрос. Не знаю получится ли это, но поинтересоваться стоит. Есть к примеру пути, системные данные и многое другое что хотелось бы загурзить очень быстро. Как можно очень быстро инициализировать объекты/поля очень быстро, во время например:

```
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeProfileData();
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      navigateFromSplash();
    });
  }

Future initializeProfileData() async {
    String accessToken = await LocalStorage.instance.storage.read(key: 'accessToken');
    if (model.accessToken != null) {
      String photoUrl = await LocalStorage.instance.storage.read(key: 'photoUrl');
      var response = await Dio().get(photoUrl, options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes));
      fileProvider.saveInputFile('avatar.jpg', response.data);
    } else {
      model.setLoggedIn(false);
    }
  }
```

То есть хотелось бы поставить таймер. И запустить на инициализацию данные. В этом случае загрузка аппа идет долговато как по мне так как сначала идет инициализация, а потом дополнительно еще и таймер запускается.
Можете дать советы как это осуществить побыстрее ну и организовать нормальный кеш?

Comment: `загрузка аппа идет долговато как по мне`, это в дебаг режиме? Попробуйте запустить релизную версию. (Это не решение, просто необходимо убедиться.)

Comment: @Mit не подумал об этом. Включил release и все начало летать. Благодарю)

Answer (score 1):

Решение довольно простое: собрать `release` версию.

Почему так происходит:

1. Компиляция под конкретные архитектуры (`armeabi-v7a (ARM 32-bit), arm64-v8a (ARM 64-bit), и x86-64 (x86 64-bit)`)
2. Отсутствует виртуальная машина Dart (Используется лишь тот код
   который нужен для работы приложения + [Skia](https://skia.org/) для отрисовки).
3. Убирается весь `debug` код.
4. Приложение оптимизировано для быстрого запуска, быстрого исполнения и небольших размеров.

По этому приложение может по разному вести себя при `debug` и `release` версии сборки.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно запустить проект следующей командой и будет значительный прирост производительности, но без возможности отладки.

```
flutter run --release
```